# Start loading bar on specific div javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have loading bar in specific div, that is 700px from top of the page. JavaScript for loading bar is working fine, but it is triggered at the start page, and when I reach to specific div, bar is already loaded, what I want is to start loading when I reach to that div. Please, help.

JavaScript:

```
<script>

$('.numberprogress[data-percentage]').each(function () {
  var progress = $(this);
  var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
  $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
    duration: 5000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
    var pct = '';
    if(percentage == 0){
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
    }else{
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
    }
    progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="middle>
<div class="progress"><div class="numberprogress" data-percentage="80"></div>
<div class="progressbar"><div class="progresspercent"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#38B1CC;
    margin-top:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0.8em;
}

.numberprogress{
    float:left;
    height:18px;
    width:18%;
    color:white;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    padding: 9px 0px;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin:5px;
}

.progressbar{
    margin-left:0px;
    float:right;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin:5px;
    height:10px;
    width:75%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
    margin-top:18px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.progresspercent{
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.middle{
    height:600px;
    width:auto;
    font-family:Bizon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of load it on DOM ready or onload event, you should load it when it reach that specific div.

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('.target-div').offset().top) {
 Your function
}
```

Comment: Could you give me example? I can't figure out how to do that in my code.

Answer (score 0):

To add on @Syahrul answer, here is a working example:[a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/yk854kdy/1/)

```
$(document).scroll(function () {    
$('.numberprogress[data-percentage]').each(function () {        
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
        animateProgress($(this));
    }
});});
```